# gcm returns service not available

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code. I enter the project key from the Google console as the snederId and get an error:
service not available.

which steps would you recommend for me to double check in setting up the registration key?

```
private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over
                    // HTTP, so it
                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    saveRegIdToDb();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the
                    // device will send
                    // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                    // using the
                    // 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                // mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some basic checks:

- Was your project whitelisted by Google?
- Do you use the correct sender_id (project number)?
- Is network connection up?
- Are Google Play Services installed and up to date?

One of the above checks should not be OK.

Answer (score 0):

check sender id, it is project number
[image]

and turn on "APIs & auth" -> "Google Cloud Messaging for Android"